# Looking for tips on 'ca' letter combination

Tags: logo, typography, ligatures

[image]I'm wondering if anyone has any tips to help make this 'ca' letter combination look better.
Thanks.[image]

Comment: That font is monospaced. TBH it's probably not a good idea to adjust the kerning. Can you change the font?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to clarify some things: 1) What’s the purpose of this design and at what size(s) it is intended to be viewed? For example, is it a for a logo? 2) Why do you want to improve this particular combination? What displeases you?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

The ca looks somehow weak between substantially richer n and p. Clip the horizontal serifs off and readjust the letter spacing.

[image]

I guess there's numerous serif and sans-serif fonts which look more balanced in your case - no tinkering except careful placement if you do not have InDesign or other typesetting program which knows something of visual appearance.

Just one example (Bodoni MT bold)

[image]

Comment: Nice adjustment. I kind of like the slabs, though.